# How to download a file that has no extension in url? or bypass download prompt?

Tags: javascript, html, url, curl, php-7

When clicking on the following link a file is generated and I get a prompt to download and save it to my computer https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/Grupo_BMV/Informacion_de_emisora/_rid/541/_mto/3/_mod/doDownload?idTipoMercado=CGEN_GLOB&idTipoInstrumento=CGEN_ELGA&idTipoEmpresa=&idSector=&idSubsector=&idRamo=&idSubramo=&random=9493

I'm trying to create a webpage that automatically downloads this file to the server, the problem is that whenever I click on the link I get a prompt to download it to my computer instead.

I attempted this

```
<a href='<?php echo "$urlAc";?>' download>Actualizar Acciones globales</a>
```

But I believe that would only work if that was the file's URL.

I attempted this as well, without positive results

```
echo file_put_contents($file, fopen($urlAc, 'r'));
```

Are there any alternatives to directly generate and download the file to my server?

Comment: _"I attempted this as well, without positive results"_  what results did you get?

Comment: A very ugly binary file, that looked like this: \D0\CFࡱ\E1\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 and so on. Thanks to your comment I realized that was the file I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phil I realized `file_put_contents($file, fopen($urlAc, 'r'));` was working correctly. I downloaded the file as 'sample.txt', then renamed it to 'sample.xls' and it worked perfectly!